# How to indent minted code blocks?

Tags: indentation, minted, code, org-mode

I'm using org-mode to generate the pdf and set the code backend to `minted`. The org source is shown as below:

```
Some text.

#+begin_src c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!);
}
#+end_src

Some text.
```

And here's the result:

[image]

What I want is the code block has an indentation like ones at the first line of paragraphs.

Comment: Welcome to TeXSe. // I understand you want to show source code in a Latex document. However, because Latex offers so many things, we need to see your Latex code as well to help you. Kindly expand your code example using the Edit button. Thanks.

Comment: @MS-SPO They're using org-mode and only converting it to LaTeX; the above *is* pretty much all their code. In regular LaTeX you could use `[xleftmargin=\parindent]` as an option to the minted environment, but I don't know how to pass options to the environment in org-mode.

Comment: Try `#+ATTR_LATEX: :options xleftmargin=\parindent` right before the src block.

Comment: @TeXnician That worked! Much thanks to you.